# Designing for mobile web browsers

Tags: mobile, mobile-web

What is the best approach for designing a web site to run across most all modern mobile web browsers?

Is targeting WebKit based browsers enough?

Comment: Semi-duplicate of http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/268/user-accessibility-for-mobile-applications

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, targeting WebKit is not enough. The first thing to do is to consider there are two segments of the mobile market: touch-based and not touch-based. This affects how you design your mobile user experience. Thankfully, the touch-based ones are going to trend significantly toward WebKit (Android, iPhone and WebOS). The others are primarily going to be IE Mobile (IE Mobile 6 on Windows Mobile 6.5 and a new one based on IE7/IE8 on Windows Phone 7) and Opera (Mobile and  Mini). Refer to this [list of mobile browsers on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_browser) for more information about rendering engines and capabilities.

For touch-based platforms, a library like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) can help you create comparable experiences across all devices, but it's going to be hard to create equal experiences across all devices. In fact, I recommend you **don't try**. The difference between touch and non-touch mobile platforms is becoming so big it's almost like the UX difference of trying to fit a desktop based UI onto a mobile sized screen - which works okay on touch-based platforms since they use iPhone's "zoom" paradigm - but you'll be hard-pressed to get anything useful out of that approach for older or non-touch platforms.

However, consider LukeW's article and subsequent talks on [designing for mobile first](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1117), which isn't necessarily an answer to your question but can be considered as a good principle: start designing by identifying the things consumers want to do on your site, and make those things available quickly and easily. That much is consistently good design across *all* platforms, so in that sense you can use that as a pattern guiding your mobile design.

Answer (score 4):

I made some experiments yesterday with an iPhone 3. Here is my experiences:

- Don't assume width is 320 pixels,
  thus use a fluid width layout.
- Use the right doctype. I use the XHTML Mobile 1.2. But I'm not sure if this is the right one.
- Make the buttons huge.
- No hover, so use icons to indicate what the different ui elements does.

Answer (score 3):

The term mobile is growing outside the realm of phones and beginning to include devices like tablets, which entail five to nine inch touch screens. Additionally, a mobile design should account for both horizontal and vertical orientations. On top of what neoneye said, a few more recommendations/suggestions.

- Use some margin or padding to make sure no text sits right at the edge of the screen.
- On top of using a fluid width layout (widths can go from 320px to 1024px), make sure design elements you use wrap well. For example, buttons look better wrapped than a horizontal list.
- Text needs to be a bit bigger, but still legible. In my view, good typographic style is at least just as important here. [The Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web](http://webtypography.net/) is a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

If your audience can be qualified a bit more then you might be able to make some educated assumptions that most customers are using a primary device or rendering browser. Address the core needs of your primary audience first. Attempting to distribute your application across all platforms equally in the "beginning" might be too daunting a task.

Here are some helpful articles I have come across:

**Mobile Reference**
http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/